# SignalR disconnect issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have the below code in the client side where it continuously connect to hub

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

But there are situations where the disconnection happens due to server issue or lets say internet connection.  I want to do the following in that case. I want to check the connection (ConnectToHubIfNotConnected()) state each time some event occurs from client side. If it is disconnected I want to connect and do the operation.

```
$("#myButton").on("click", { foo: "bar" }, function () {
            if (ConnectToHubIfNotConnected()) //Connect to hub if not
            {
                //Do the operation
            }
});
```

I have to check the connection state every time user perform some event. It looks little odd and repetitive to me to write the same thing over and over for all the events. Do we have a better option? Can I get a better version of the code please.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of SignalR you use but SignalR has built-in abilities for such problem. You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#transportdisconnect

Comment: I am using signalR 2.1. I have gone through the document. My question is once OnDisconnected event fires and user clicks any button then error will be displayed. To tackle the situation do i have to manually connect to the hub? if yes how?

Comment: any solution till now ?